# increase image size by percent on mouseover

Tags: percentage, onmouseover, image-enlarge

I am making a website on Weebly.  I want all images to increase in size on mouseover.  Some of them are different sizes, so I would like to do it by percent.  I found a code and tried editing it myself, but it is not working.  Here is the code I tried using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').mouseover(grow);
$('img').mouseout(shrink);
});

function grow(){
$(this).css('height','150%');
$(this).css(‘width’,’auto’)
}

function shrink(){
$(this).css('height','100%');
$(this).css(‘width’,’auto’)
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.  :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that it is not working.   In what way is it not working, what is the html for the image?  provided enough that the issue can be recreated.

Comment: The images do nothing on mouseover.  I do not know what the html for the image is...  If you tell me how to find it, I will tell you what it is.